# Does react-redux call the ReactDOM.render since I cant se it and the React app works

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Beginner question, I saw this [amazing react-redux tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/) and notice that it does not use `ReactDOM.render`

Is react-redux handling that?

Comment: No... It's there at the root index... In the article they are using destructuring `import { render } from "react-dom";`

Comment: create an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article, you have referenced they are using it here:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./js/store/index";
import App from "./js/components/App";

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

They are simply destructuring it which is not uncommon. `Redux` is simply a global state management library (completely independent of `React` or `ReactDOM`)... If you are using `React` with `Redux` you must also use `react-redux` lib (that's where they're getting the provider in the example above... You can think of `react-redux` as the "glue" between them...